# "Remember you can select this as the best answer" message should mention wait time (if there is one)

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, accepted-answer, up-votes, popups

At the moment, if you vote up an answer to your question and you haven't chosen a "best answer" it will pop up a notice reminding you that you can. If you then try to select it as the best answer it will pop up another message saying that you have to wait x minutes if the minimum time since question was asked hasn't run out.

It would be nice if the x minutes you have to wait until you can choose a best answer was mentioned in the first message.

Something like "Remember you can select this answer as the best answer in x minutes".

Comment: Is there a name for this kind of design flaw? Where the system implies you can or should do something, and then immediately tells you that you cannot do that thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is completely counter to the intention here to give people a timer -- the only reason we block accepts for a VERY LIMITED 15 MINUTE WINDOW after question asking is because people accept *too soon*, before people have had a chance to weigh in properly.

Declining because:

- Doing this would only encourage more clock-watching and explicitly send the wrong "you should accept as soon as humanly possible" message
- It only matters for the first 15 minutes after asking the question